# Setting default values and using error input with Laravel 4 forms?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 and its built-in form component. I'm trying to set it so that I can give the form set of default values, but if the user submits and the validator fails, it will use the values from the previous input. The code below, however, always fails. The session value 'threw_error' is always true for some reason, even when the form throws errors.

It seems that everything is done with sessions, which is why I'm setting __old_input, an internal key that the form uses. What am I doing wrong? Should I be using __old_input like this, or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

I'm using resourceful controllers, so index() below is GET /, and store() is POST /.

```php
class Admin_DetailsController extends Admin_BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {           
        $details = Detail::all();

        // this is always true for some reason?
        if(!Session::get('threw_error', false))
        {
            Session::put('__old_input', $details);          
        }

        $data['message'] = Session::get('message');

        $this->layout->nest('content', 'admin.details.index', $data);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $validator = $this->makeValidator();
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::to('/admin/details')->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with('threw_error', 1);
        }

        // process normally
    }
}

// in view
{{ Form::text('some_field') }}
```

**Edit:** This code works as expected, more or less, though Session::flashInput($details) is better than manually calling __old_input. I tried removing some fields in the form to see if it was something there, and this actually worked. In other words, I think it's an issue with either my local version of PHP, or some config or something - and not a Laravel issue.

Answer (score 7):

As of Laravel 4 you can do [Form::model($model, array)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L124) instead of `Form::open(array)`

Then you don't have to pass value to the Form helper methods. It will get the value from the model, but first, it's gonna check if there is oldInput, so the value will be the old one.

Check out this [method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L745). It's a small change, but really smart one :)

But for this to work, you have to redirect back with the input

```php
Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

Like so:

```php
public function createNew()
{
    $data = array(
        'model' => new Model();
    );

    $this->layout->nest('content', 'admin.details.form', $data);
}

public function store()
{
    $validator = $this->makeValidator();
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
}

// In the view
{{ Form::model($model, array(...)) }}

    // The first time it will be null
    // But if the validation fails, it will be the old value 
    {{ Form::text('some_field', 'Some fields title') }} 

{{ Form::close()}}
```

PS instead of using the `Session::flashInput()`, you can use `Input::old()`